# Add "-" instead of spaces in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to add the "-" carector instead of speces in the below column in my select statement:

```
SPACE(([Depth]-1)*4) + [OrgUnitName] AS [OrgUnitName],
```

So right now it adds spaces for however many depths there are. Is it possible to have this add the "-" charector instead of the spaces? The data is locations so it could have spaces between the words as well.

So for:

```
Test
 Test2
  Test23
```

I want:

```
Test
-Test2
--Test23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`REPLICATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx):

```
REPLICATE ( string_expression ,integer_expression )
```

That is

```
REPLICATE ('-', ([Depth]-1)*4) + [OrgUnitName] AS [OrgUnitName],
```

in your case.

However I prefer to return `Depth` as an output column and format the dashes with code. As little formatting and logic as possible in the SQL queries increases maintainability in my experience.